# Unable to install E:\reactnative\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apkcom.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to install all'

Tags: react-native

When I run '`react-native run-android`', throw '**Installing APK 'app-debug.apk`' on 'MX4 - 5.1**' for app:debug

> Unable to install
>   E:\reactnative\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apkcom.android.ddmlib.InstallException:
>   Failed to install all'

who can help me?

Comment: try running react-native start and build the project from android studio..

Comment: device or emulator?